# Changing application theme programmatically(not inside main activity)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I need to set the application theme according to the user preference. This process happens in separate activity and it is not my main activity. I used this code to change the application theme:

```
getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.theme);
```

I know that it is perfectly work if I used it before

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
```

methods inside onCreate() method. But I have to do it in separate method. I tried to restart the application after that code as follows but it is not restart the application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Also I don't have any idea after restarting the application that it would work. 
**Any suggestion would be appreciated to solve the problem to change the application theme programmatically .**

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, it restarts the application after one second:

```
private void restartSelf() {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 1000, // one second
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    finish();
}
```

`restartSelf()` should be a member of your main activity. Alternatively, you may replace `this` with your application's context and  and `getIntent()` with the main activity's `Intent`.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I tried this. Application re-open again though previous window still open. But my problem is not solve. The new theme does not apply.

Comment: I found the issue. As you said when I used this code inside main activity it works well. But I have to restart the application within another activity. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: As @jak10h has mentioned, persist the user choice and a boolean value (e.g., `themeChanged`) that indicates that user has changed the theme. When user changes the theme: 1) Set `themeChanged` to true; 2) Finish `another activity`; 3) In `main activity`s `onResume()` call `restartSelf()` if `themeChanged` is true; 4) Set `themeChanged` to false in `restartSelf()`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, can you try saving the user preference choice?
After the user chooses a theme, you can save the choice in persistent memory (such as shared preferences) and after the select, restart the application. In the onCreate of the main activity, you can access the user choice and set the theme there before super.onCreate( ) by accessing the persistent memory.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try on this and let you know. :)